# Native CMS in IBM Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-tools, ibm-cloud-plugin

We are trying to migrate our corporate web which is build in php and laravel to IBM. This web has his own CMS.

So the question is if there is a CMS native than can run in IBM Bluemix, or if IBM has his own CMS.

We found Box in IBM Cloud Foundry, but we don't know if this is a real and a good option for we are looking.

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can run your PHP/Laravel CMS on IBM Cloud, using the Cloud Foundry PHP Runtime, start here https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/starters/php or you might find this blog post from another user helpful https://akrabat.com/deploying-a-php-application-to-cloud-foundry/.

Answer (score 0):

IBM Cloud Object Store is the CMS service in IBM Cloud.

It’s wrapped in a REST API and is built to nearly the same specifications as Amazon S3.

Essentially a file system wrapped in REST.